# ExtJS Toolbar buttons stay focused

Tags: extjs, extjs4

The problem on ExtJS is that if I click on toolbar button it stay focused.

You can try it in first live demo [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar).

In case if this `button` is toggle `button` for user it looks like `selected` when user `deselect` it and only after user `click` somewhere else `focus` is gone and user see that `button` is not selected.

Developers of Ext already accept this as a bug, but didn't fix it in new versions.

Is anyone has workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but the behavior is still there. 
Since I'm using a group of toggle buttons and "click" event handler (you can also use "toggle" event) I have added simple fix.

My buttons are inside of toolbar, so:

```
onBtnClick : function(btn) {    
    var toolbar = btn.up('toolbar');
    if(!btn.pressed){
     toolbar.focus();
    }
    /*Main handler code...*/
}
```

It does not fix the root cause of this problem, so you probably can dig into ExtJS code to fix it. Anyway, it's simple and seems to be harmless - and the buttons behave as they should.